# How to exit Ctrl+R search history command?

Tags: command-line

In Terminal when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, we can search through the command history. However, if we do not find what we want, how can we go back to the directory prompt, and not have any of the search results displayed?

Comment: I guess one workaround is to Alt+P Backspace

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Excerpt of `man readline`:

> SEARCHING Readline  provides  commands  for searching through the
>   command history for lines containing a specified string.  There are
>   two search modes: incremental and non-incremental.
>
> Incremental searches begin before the user has finished typing the
>   search string.  As each character of the search string is  typed, 
>   readline  displays  the next  entry  from the history matching the
>   string typed so far.  An incremental search requires only as many
>   characters as needed to find the desired history entry.  To search
>   backward in the history for a particular string, type C-r.  Typing C-s
>   searches forward through the history.  The characters present in the
>   value  of  the  isearch-terminators  variable are used to terminate an
>   incremental search.  If that variable has not been assigned a value
>   the Escape and C-J characters will terminate an incremental search. 
>   **C-G will abort an incremental search**  and restore the original line. 
>   When the  search  is  terminated,  the history entry containing the
>   search string becomes the current line.
>
> To  find  other  matching entries in the history list, type C-s or C-r
>   as appropriate.  This will search backward or forward in the history
>   for the next line matching the search string typed so far.  Any other
>   key sequence bound to a readline command will  terminate  the  search 
>   and  execute  that  command.   For instance,  a  newline  will
>   terminate the search and accept the line, thereby executing the
>   command from the history list.  A movement command will terminate the
>   search, make the last line found the current line, and begin editing.
>
> Non-incremental searches read the entire search string before starting
>   to search for matching history lines.  The search string may be typed
>   by the  user  or be part of the contents of the current line.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something today :)

Comment: Ctrl + C also aborts the search and returns the original line(For experience, dunno about documentation)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Both will get you out of the search command.
The difference is that <kbd>Esc</kbd> will keep the last searched command, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will exit the command completely.

Answer (score 2):

Exit from history search with <kbd>ESC</kbd>

Comment: "When the search is terminated, the history entry containing the search string becomes the current line." It means that if there's one result, although not the one is being looking for, pressing ESC will leave that result in the screen. That's not what OP wants.